# MongoDB in PHP(Yii framework). Find with condition

Tags: php, mongodb, yii, php-mongodb

how to find in my collection of all the values ​​where the field "date" = "current date"?

i have:

```
$cursor = $mongo->$db->$collection->find(array('date_of_download' => date('Y-m-d',time()) ));
```

but found only field "date_of_download"

In Mongo query with conditions:

```
$in

The $in operator is analogous to the SQL IN modifier, allowing you to specify an array    of possible matches.

db.collection.find( { field : { $in : array } } );
```

but how do I write it in Yii?

Comment: are you want to search into mutiple field or one field and multiple values ?

Comment: search by one field multiple values

Comment: please check and try my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it work as below

```
//Mongo Syntax
db.collection.find( { field : { $in : array } } );
```

To (in PHP + Yii)

```
//This example
$cursor = $mongo->$db->$collection->find(array('date_of_download' => array('$in' => array('2012-09-11', '2012-09-12'))));
```

Comment: I get MongoCursorTimeoutException' with message 'cursor timed out'
I searched in DB where 6 million records, maybe it's a reason?

Comment: @EugenShevchuk The timeout means that the cursor simply timed out, this is not a PHP issue normally but a Mongo one, normally to do with the query taking too long, can you do this query in the Mongo console and add an `.explain()` to the end and edit your question with it?

Comment: @EugenShevchuk yes agree with Sammaye .. please try as he suggested

Comment: but how do I get to the console?

Comment: go to your server, then type mongo dbname; then enter

Comment: @EugenShevchuk Getting the console app itself depends on your OS, but within the mongo directory there should be a program named simply `mongo` or `mongo.exe` in windows case, double click and run it

Comment: i tried
> db.collection.find( { date_of_download : { $in : array('2012-10-16') } } );
and get 
Tue Oct 16 10:47:39 ReferenceError: array is not defined (shell):1

Comment: @EugenShevchuk instead of array use `[ISODate('16-10-2012')]`

Comment: i get: Tue Oct 16 10:57:18 uncaught exception: invalid ISO date

Comment: @EugenShevchuk Did you use it with the space? it is `ISODate()` as shown here: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Dates

Comment: i use  
    db.collection.find( { date_of_download : { $in : ISODate('16-10-2012') } } );

also i tried: 
    ISODate('16-10-2012') and ISODate() and [ISODate('16-10-2012')]

Comment: Try db.collection.find( { date_of_download : { $in : [ISODate('16-10-2012')] } } );

Comment: and i tried
`$current_date = date('d-m-Y',time());
$cursor = $mongo->$db->$collection->find(array('date_of_download' => array('$in' => $current_date)));`
and get:  'MongoCursorException' with message 'invalid query'

Comment: @EugenShevchuk that's because as GBD says $in takes an array (or `[]` in JS) of dates, it won't take a single date.

Comment: @GBD i get `uncaught exception: invalid ISO date`

Comment: how you stored your date into db ? can you paste sample ?

Comment: `[_id] => MongoId Object (
        [$id] => 4f4baedbc6838823164b9dad
)
[serial-number] => 77894764

[date_of_download] => 16-10-2012`

Comment: @EugenShevchuk Ok so it is in string form, try: `db.collection.find( { date_of_download : { $in : ['16-10-2012'] } } );`

Comment: i tried `db.collection.find( { date_of_download : { $in : ['16-10-2012'] } } );`
and nothing happens, without error

Comment: for your php error: you need to pass array $current_date = date('d-m-Y',time()); $cursor = $mongo->$db->$collection->find(array('date_of_download' => array('$in' => array($current_date))));

Comment: Also try to se timeout while query $current_date = date('d-m-Y',time()); $cursor = $mongo->$db->$collection->find(array('date_of_download' => array('$in' => array($current_date))))->timeout();

Comment: @EugenShevchuk Wait you are using `db.collection`? you should replace `collection` with your collection name that your querying